Saving an pandas dataframe with empty value into nvarchar column in SQL Server table results in "n.n" being stored in the table
I'm trying to save a pandas dataframe into SQL Server using a pyodbc connection. One of my columns called validation in the dataframe consists of JSON strings, and the corresponding SQL Server column is an nvarchar(max) column.
The values in the validation column that are not empty get saved in the SQL Server table without issues.
The values that are empty, represented as NaN show up in the SQL Server table as n.n.
Other columns in the SQL Server table that are nullable don't have this issue, and I am not able to figure out why this issue is occurring.
The column in question looks like:
> df['column']
0    [{"a":true...
1    [{"b":false...
2               NaN
3               NaN
4               NaN

[{"a":true...
[{"b":false...
n.n
n.n
n.n

Any ideas as to what causes this issue?

it seem to consist of Dictionaries not json strings

You need to convert your NaN values to None, NaN values are numeric type and will be converted to floating points. That's why you're getting n.n .
